# How to capitalize the second appearance of the same variable in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm, live-templates

I have the following WebStorm Live Template:

`[$VAR1$, set$VAR1$]`

My goal is to capitalize the second occurrence of `$VAR1$`.

e.g. for the input: `foo`
the output should be: `[foo, setFoo]`
right now the output is: `[foo, setfoo]`

For Live Templates, there is a Dialog where I can define a function expression to capitalize a variable:
[image]

The problem here is that the definition is per variable, so both occurrences are capitalized then.

How can I capitalize only the second occurrence, or copy the value of one variable into another one which would be capitalized then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add another variable:

```
$VAR1$, set$VAR2$
```

[image]

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2022/02/creating-and-using-code-snippets-with-placeholders/, you may find this blog post useful